# Is word (like) etus likely to appear on 19th Century Cornwall Will?

Tags: palaeography, cornwall, will

I have largely transcribed the 1840 Will of my 4th great grandfather William Symons of Helston in Cornwall but there is one word which eludes me and it appears twice.

It looks to me like `etus` and I have included two images of it and some surrounding words for context below.

I think this says "benefit for ever `etus` I do appoint"

[image]

and I think this says "and forty now accounts annexed `etus`"

[image]

(the "and forty" bit is the end of the year 1840 being spelled out and the next line starts "this deponent further made oath")

Is there a word (like) `etus` that is likely to appear on an 1840 Will from Cornwall?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's "And" with a capital "A" !

Your "s" is clearly(?) the same as the "d" in "and"

Your "u" could just as easily be an "n" - these are notoriously easy to confuse.

Your "et" is one letter, "A" - the second "etus" is actually clearer that the "et" is one letter.

It doesn't help that they omit punctuation, does it?

Comment: Many thanks - had not considered they might start a sentence with And (and no full stop preceding) - but that fits perfectly now that you have pointed it out.